# Convert percentile change to Cohen's d

Tags: distributions, effect-size, quantiles, standardization, cohens-d

tl;dr: How do I convert from percentile change to Cohen's d for the whole distribution?

A common measure of effect size is Cohen's d: the mean difference between an experiment and control group divided by the pooled standard deviation. An alternative approach is to express effect size in terms of changes in percentile rank.

Cohen's d and percentile change assume different underlying distributions (standard normal vs uniform). Therefore, converting from one to the other requires a specific percentile relative to which change is taking place. There are conversion tables for this that give the equivalent of d for one percentile point's change starting from a given place in the distribution.

Here is my question: Suppose I have estimated a treatment effect on a whole population that I am able to express in terms of percentile rank, for example, the whole population shifted 5 percentiles upward.

Is there an established way to convert this to an effect size expressed on the Cohen's d scale? Note that I want the Cohen's d for shifting the whole distribution n percentile points, not for a shift starting from a given percentile.